# expected number in from data in data.frame in R

Tags: r

I want to turn this equation into an R code: ((e^-mean)(mean^i)/i!)XN; where i = index and N is sample size.

What I have is this:

```
x["expected92"]<-((exp(-me92))(me92^(x$multX1992))/(x$multX1992));
```

I want to create a new column that goes through the index and makes the expected mean.

example data:

```
Drag 1992 multX1992 
0 113 0
1 30 30
3 15 30
```

example of wanted output:

```
Drag 1992 multX1992 expected92
0 113 0 90.03
1 30 30 58.80
3 15 30 19.20
```

Can someone help fix my code?

Comment: you always need to use operators in r [citation needed]. `((exp(-me92)) * (me92^(x$multX1992))/(x$multX1992))`. Also you should avoid dividing by zero. I don't have a citation for that, either

Comment: For a citation on the first point you could use section: `3.1.4 Operators` which is in the "Evaluation of Expressions" section in "R Language Definition".

Comment: Thanks everyone, I cant believe I made such a dumb mistake. Cheers